# App or software to show students live step by step in Math?

Tags: web-apps, math, ipad-app

I am looking for a software or an app that allow my wife to show her students. She teaches 7th grade in Math and I am trying to find one that she can use to upload them in her online classroom ?

Due to her school closed because of the coronavirus situation, do you have a suggest one that would be easier for her ?

She could use her IPAD Pro and use live with her fingers pointing step by step .

Is there a one ?

Answer (score 1):

If using Zoom is not an option, using [sidecar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380) is a great option if you're on a Mac.  It allows you to use your iPad as a second display and can use whatever software you'd like, draw on apps like Notability, or even use the Zoom whiteboard.  It's really powerful and I definitely recommend it for teachers and tutors (like myself).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Zoom](https://zoom.us/download) which is also free on ipad.